# Why my rails associations don't work in controller but they work in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, instance-variables

I've got `User has_one Shop` & `Shop has_many Branches`.

When I do this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @shop = @user.shop
    @branches = @shop.branches
  end
...
```

The `@user` & `@shop` instance variable works in view, but `@branches` gives me the error:

```
undefined method `branches' for nil:NilClass

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:13:in `show'
```

---

However, if I discard `@branches` in the controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @shop = @user.shop
  end
...
```

....and use this in the view:

```
@shop.branches
```

....it works! It's kinda tiring to use `@shop.branches` in the view all the time, so I prefer to just use `@branches`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message indicates that `@shop` is nil in the controller. If with the same request it works in the view, it means that certainly `@shop` has been set somewhere else after the controller.